# Using Zend Without Installation in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using PHP Blogger API ,

The code use

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
```

I was Struggling two days for installation of Zend.But i am unable to do it.Is there anyway to use Zend/Loader.php without installation ? by just uploading files to public_html ?

Comment: That should work no problem, you can use ZF by just including the files on the PHP include path. What error are you getting?

Comment: /library/Zend/.classmap.php"' not found error

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a *ZF2* error message, yet the classes referenced are ZF1 pseudo-namespaced classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the autloader, it weas changed after ZF1 1.8

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

http://devzone.zend.com/1448/developing-a-comprehensive-autoloader/